# Let $A$ be a countable set of real numbers. Prove that $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ is dense

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be a countable set of real numbers. Prove that $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ is dense.

I thought that the best way to solve this question was by using a proof by contradiction and saying that $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ is not dense.

Comment: In my opinion, showing that $A$ has empty interior would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Apply Baire Category theorem to the family of sets $\mathbb{R} \setminus {a}$ for $a \in A$.

Comment: +1 for neat "big hammer" proof (although probably not of much use to the OP), such as can be found in [Awfully sophisticated proof for simple facts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42512/awfully-sophisticated-proof-for-simple-facts) and this [20-25 October 1999 sci.math thread](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=206856).

Answer (score 1):

"Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary and $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary open set containing $x$.  Then $U$ is uncountable, so $U \smallsetminus A \neq \varnothing$. ..."